# In jmeter is it correct to decrese number of threads and increase reqest(copy of same request) to increase response time

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

In my application when i execute 2000 virtual users in thread(No: of threads) for 1 http request my response time was 30 sec , when i changed no of threads to 500 and instead of 1 http request I put 4 copies of same http request, RESPONSE TIME WAS 3 SEC . What is the difference? Is it the right way to reduce no of threads and increasing replicas of request? please help 
Note: In each reqest i have changed the user id also

Answer (score 0):

In terms of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers your test must behave exactly like real browser behaves so artificially adding more HTTP Requests may (and will) break the logic of your workload (if it is in place).

In your case high response time seems to be caused by incorrect JMeter configuration, i.e. if JMeter is not properly configured to high load it simply will not be able to fire requests fast enough resulting in increased response time while your server will just be idle.

2000 threads sounds like quite a big number so make sure to:

- Follow [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- Follow recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) especially these:

  - Increase [JVM Heap size](https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space) allocated for JMeter
  - Run your test in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
  - Remove all the [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) from the Test Plan
- Monitor baseline OS health metrics on the machine where JMeter is running (CPU, RAM, Disk, Network usage). You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this. If you will notice the lack of any of the aforementioned resources, i.e. usage will start exceeding, say, 90% of total available capacity - JMeter is not acting at full speed and you will need to consider [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).

Answer (score 0):

To extend @Dmitri T answer, If your server response 10 times more on load, as you execute 2000 virtual users, it means there's a bottleneck that you need to identify.

Read JMeter's [Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

> consider running multiple **non-GUI** JMeter instances on multiple machines using [distributed mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

Also check `Delay Thread creation until needed` checkbox in Thread Group

> JMeter has an option to delay thread creation until the thread starts sampling, i.e. after any thread group delay and the ramp-up time for the thread itself. This allows for a very large total number of threads, provided that not too many are active concurrently.

And set [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) Ramp-up to 2000

> Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.